# Harddisk working principle

Tags: hard-drive

I have 10 bytes data to write to a file, after my program writes 9 bytes and 7 bits to hard disk, if electricity cuts, how many bytes can I read from this file after electricity arrives? 9 bytes or 10 bytes?

Comment: You cannot write individual bits to a disk. There is a minimum block size.

Comment: And even that is not much related to what the file system thinks where a file starts and ends, and what kind of measures it has in place to protect from incomplete updates.

Comment: So can I say that if minimum block size is 512 byte, I can read zero bytes. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't say anything. There's too many layers of abstraction here. Your program often buffers, the OS buffers, the chipset buffers, the drive itself buffers, and at some point the data will be written.

When you ask for a hard sync on the data through something like [`fsync`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sync_(Unix)) all you're getting is a confirmation that *at least* your data was written, no guarantee that nothing else was.

It takes non-zero amounts of time for this data to stream through all those layers and physically end up on your disk, SSD or otherwise. If power cuts at some point in this process and you haven't received a write confirmation the safe thing to assume is you do not know how much was written. You'll have to inspect whatever files you were writing to before and see what data is present.

When your system reboots it will probably have to recover from the journal anyway, and any uncommitted changes will be rolled back. In your example the number of bytes actually written is **zero**.